# oracle PLS-00103 Error after executing a simple query

Tags: oracle, pls-00103

this is the code that I ran in the Oracle SQL Developer and the error has come next:
It is a very simple query so what's wrong whit it?

```
DECLARE zero varchar(20);
DECLARE emptys;
begin
zero := '0';
emptys := null;
IF(emptys = zero)   then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('yes');
ELSE
dbms_output.Put_line('no'); 
end if;
end;
```

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE zero varchar(20);
DECLARE emptys;
begin
zero := '0';
emptys := null;

```
IF(emptys = zero)   then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('yes');
ELSE
dbms_output.Put_line('no'); 
end if;
```

end;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
 current cursor delete
exists prior
The symbol "begin was inserted before "DECLARE" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 13, column 74:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 
 << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query
json_object json_array
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECLARE` indicates the beginning of the variable declaration section.  You'd only have one such section.  You don't repeat that keyword for every variable you declare.

You haven't provided a data type for the variable `emptys`.  I'll assume you want that to be `varchar2(20)`

```
DECLARE 
  zero varchar(20);
  emptys varchar2(20);
begin
  zero := '0';
  emptys := null;
  IF(emptys = zero)   then 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('yes');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.Put_line('no'); 
  end if;
end;
```